# I need to change a Registry entry/value using CMD 32

Tags: windows-10

Im not much of a pc expert but anything will help.

if i boot pc it goes to a black screen with a cursor and gives me no access to task manager or no windows feature other than Windows Kwy + P to project menu. If i go into windows recovery mode and go to command prompt i can then get to task manager but gives me no access device manager or anything i dont know if i need to change file path maybe before typing "taskmgr.

Anyways i was told on the [LTT FORUM](https://linustechtips.com/main/topic/860115-solved-windows-10-black-screen-with-system32-cmd-prompt/page/2/) entry by a user called Yonlap. i need to change the entry of

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\Shell
```

from whatever it is to "explorer.exe"

and have no clue how any help is appreciated!

Comment: At the black screen (not recovery).. does [CTRL]+[ALT]+[ESCAPE] pull up the task manager?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command line registry edit](https://superuser.com/questions/867652/command-line-registry-edit)

Answer (score 0):

The value of that key should be explorer.exe - I see it on my system. A person can use Regedit (comes with Windows), but I strongly suggest you get a knowledgeable person to help you. A mis-step can screw things up further.

It is possible the registry key you refer to is OK. Then, the issue above warrants doing a Windows 10 Repair Install. Use the Media Creation link (the second link - Download), run in place, and at the appropriate spot, start with the option to Keep Everything.  Once complete, see if your issue has been resolved.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Comment: yeah thank you for confirming

Comment: I bet it is ALREADY set to explorer.exe.  That is probably not the problem anyways.

Comment: Yes, it would be exceptionally odd for this particular value to have been changed.

Comment: You said earlier you were not experienced, so (a) the value may not have changed, but (b) you should have a knowledgeable person check that and also what the problem may be.

Comment: I added a repair option that you could do yourself if you think the registry key was not changed.